# Limit floating precision using %.f with a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, i have a result and i can limit his floating precision using this:

```
result = 0.12345
print ("Result = %.2f" % (result) ) 
#will print ~ 0.12
```

What can i do to substitute the **'2' on %.2f to a variable number**?

> Something like this:

```
from random import randint
LIMIT = randint(1,5)
#pick some random 'limit' between 1 and 5, inclusive, just to demonstrate

print ("Result = %.~LIMIT~f" % (result) )
```

Comment: You can put an asterisk in place of a format width specification, to take the width from a parameter instead.  So: `"Result = %.*f" % (LIMIT, result)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass your limit alongside the format call:

```
LIMIT = 3
result = 0.12345
print("Result = %.*f" % (LIMIT, result))  # 0.123
```

Or better yet, use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) as `%` formatting has been deprecated:

```
LIMIT = 3
result = 0.12345
print("Result = {:.{}f}".format(result, LIMIT))  # 0.123
```